# nhibernate web.config issues

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I am setting up a hibernate project and I keep on getting a proxy error.  I have already added the Castle reference to the my project.  My web.config has the following:

```
    <section name="nhibernate" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
</configSections>

<nhibernate xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=192.168.1.100, 0000;Initial Catalog=GDER;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=re;Password=none12</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
</nhibernate>
```

Yet, I get the following error consistently

> The ProxyFactoryFactory was not configured. Initialize 'proxyfactory.factory_class' property of the session-factory configuration section with one of the available >NHibernate.ByteCode providers. Example: NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu Example: NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, >NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle

The debug always fails here (`NHibernate.ISessionFactory factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();`):

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
// add our assembly
config.AddAssembly("nHibernateTest");
// setup nhibernate session
NHibernate.ISessionFactory factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
NHibernate.ISession session = factory.OpenSession();
// start nhibernate transaction
NHibernate.ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
```

Please help...

Comment: Indent each line of your code with 4 spaces to get it to display properly.  Also you need to format your posting of your web.config file so that it is readable.  You should be able to find out how to do this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  It's very hard to read like it is now.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add a reference to the proxy provider in your project (Project > Add Reference... and select NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll).

Comment: @James, have you verified NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll is being copied to your deployment folder?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a call to `config.Configure()` before adding the assembly.

Comment: +1. The book NHibernate in Action left the same line out in a code sample and it drove me up the wall trying to figure out what was wrong.